# When we must require to use In-App-Purchase in the App

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, in-app-purchase

I'm new for In-App-Purchase and need your guidance. In My App there are 4 main plans for user.  After select any one plan from it, User have to select some other sub plans.

Base on main plan and some other plans user need to make payment.

So my question is May I use any third party payment like PayPal, PayUmoney and etc Or I must need to use In-App-Purchase ?

Here little confusion please guide me.